# TF-IDF Vectors can be generated at different levels of input tokens (words, characters, n-grams) which should we use?

Tags: machine-learning, tf-idf

a. Word Level TF-IDF : Matrix representing tf-idf scores of every term in different documents.

b. N-gram Level TF-IDF : N-grams are the combination of N terms together. This Matrix representing tf-idf scores of N-grams

c. Character Level TF-IDF : Matrix representing tf-idf scores of character level

```
tfidf_vect = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', token_pattern=r'\w{1,}', max_features=5000)
tfidf_vect.fit(trainDF['texts'])
xtrain_tfidf = tfidf_vect.transform(train_x)
xvalid_tfidf = tfidf_vect.transform(valid_x)


# ngram level tf-idf N-gram Level TF-IDF : N-grams are the combination of N terms together. This 
Matrix representing tf-idf scores of N-grams
tfidf_vect_ngram = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', token_pattern=r'\w{1,}', ngram_range=(2, 3), 
max_features=5000)
tfidf_vect_ngram.fit(trainDF['texts'])
xtrain_tfidf_ngram = tfidf_vect_ngram.transform(train_x)
xvalid_tfidf_ngram = tfidf_vect_ngram.transform(valid_x)


# characters level tf-idf Character Level TF-IDF : Matrix representing tf-idf scores of character level n-grams in the dataset
tfidf_vect_ngram_chars = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='char', token_pattern=r'\w{1,}', ngram_range=(2, 3), max_features=5000)
tfidf_vect_ngram_chars.fit(trainDF['texts'])
xtrain_tfidf_ngram_chars = tfidf_vect_ngram_chars.transform(train_x)
xvalid_tfidf_ngram_chars = tfidf_vect_ngram_chars.transform(valid_x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no one right answer for all cases. The approach will depend on the nature of the data.

You should use [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) to recognize the best approach in your exact case. Here is a [good example of the pipeline for text feature extraction](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/grid_search_text_feature_extraction.html) from the official documentation.

Comment: hi sir Thanks for your time, but  my question was i have to use tf-idf  which level of tokens can be used for model, because i am getting accuracy 100% accuracy at character level and 90 percennt at Ngram level and word level  , which should i use ?